# How to make a SwiftUI Picker with arbitrary views as content

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, what is the best way of creating a `Picker` that contains arbitrary views as the entries? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker/) seems to suggest that you could use any View for the contents of the picker, but in practice, it ignores much of the content you provide.

I'm trying to make a menu that looks something like the color pickers in the Rendering Inspector of the SF Symbols app, looking like this (the Picker menu is at the bottom of the image):

[image: color menu example]

This code looked like it should do the trick:

```swift
struct PickerWithArbitraryView: View {
    @State private var selectedColor = "Black"
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Color", selection: $selectedColor) {
//            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    Text("Black")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .tag("Black")
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    Text("Red")
                    Spacer()
                }.tag("Red")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is this:

[image: result of code]

The Rectangle in my code is being ignored. If you replace the `Picker` line in the code with the commented out `VStack` below, you can see that the Views I've supplied as content are correct.

I'm using [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker/init(_:selection:content:)-6lwfn) for Picker. The only requirement it mentions is that the content should conform to View. If  SwiftUI is designed to extract just the first Text and first Image from the content, and this certainly seems to be the way it behaves, I'm surprised that it isn't mentioned in the docs anywhere. Am I missing something?

If there's a way to use arbitrary views as the contents, please let me know. Failing that, does someone have a way of specifically getting color samples into the picker?

Comment: "I'm surprised that it isn't mentioned in the docs anywhere" I assume that's because this makes it easier for Apple to change this behaviour in the future. What views the picker uses and how it lays them out is very OS-dependent, and can change in future updates. If you want your picker to look *exactly* a certain way, better not use the built-in `Picker`. That said, if you use an `Image` instead of a `Rectangle`, you will see that the image foes appear on the leading edge on macOS. On iOS however, the image appears at the trailing edge.

Comment: How annoying that you can't even use `Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill").foregroundStyle(.red)` to put a swatch of the right colour in the menu (the styling gets stripped away and you end up with a blank rectangle). Implementing my own version of Picker is not exactly trivial and involves fighting SwiftUI on many fronts.

Comment: That's because "rectangle.fill" is a symbol. If you actually make a red image (perhaps with [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(size:label:opaque:colormode:renderer:))), then it works fine. I wouldn't call making your own picker "fighting" SwiftUI. There is nothing wrong with making your own picker if you are unsatisfied with the existing one.

Comment: I can confirm that that initializer works. Thank you! Would you be able to write that up as the "failing that" Answer for me to accept? If you're too busy, let me know, and I will do it. Incidentally, making my own picker is too large a task (fighting overlay difficulties, UX issues, etc) for what's needed here. At least for me -- I suspect it would be less of a challenge for you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm surprised that it isn't mentioned in the docs anywhere

I assume that's because this makes it easier for Apple to change this behaviour in the future. What views the picker uses and how it lays them out is very OS-dependent, and can change in future updates.

As of right now, the behaviour is exactly as you have guessed - SwiftUI extracts a "textual element" and a "image-like" element from each view you give in the view builder. Note that the placement of the image is on the leading edge on macOS, but on trailing edge on iOS.

If you want your picker to look exactly a certain way, better not use the built-in `Picker`.

That said, if you are happy with the colored rectangle appearing on the trailing edge, you can manually create an `Image` from the color.

```
extension Color {
    func asImage(size: CGSize = .init(width: 25, height: 16), cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4) -> Image {
        Image(size: size) { context in
            context.fill(
                Path(
                    roundedRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: size), 
                    cornerRadius: cornerRadius
                ),
                with: .color(self))
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
HStack {
    Color.black.asImage()
    Text("Black")
}
.tag("Black")
```

It is also possible to use an SF symbol like `rectangle.fill` here. `Picker` ignores a lot of SwiftUI view modifiers, so you have to use a bit of UIKit:

```
extension UIColor {
    func asImage() -> Image {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "rectangle.fill")!
            .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            .withTintColor(self)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It's worth noting also that SwiftUI is doing something potentially surprising with the "image-like" element it puts in the menu. There's some sort of scaling-to-fit going on that you might have to deal with. Also, I'd like to link to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630755/14840926) of Sweeper's answers that might be useful to anyone who is using this answer.